# Renaming many files to their parent directory name

Tags: bash, shell-script, find, rename

I want to recursively change many files named `raw.tex` to `parent-directory-hw.tex`. Is there a simple scripting solution to this problem?

For example, running the script on

```
.
`-- root
    |-- baz
    |   `-- raw.tex
    |-- foo
    |   `-- bar
    |       `-- raw.tex
    `-- spam
        |-- eggs
        |   `-- raw.tex
        `-- raw.tex
```

should result in

```
.
`-- root
    |-- baz
    |   `-- baz-hw.tex
    |-- foo
    |   `-- bar
    |       `-- bar-hw.tex
    `-- spam
        |-- eggs
        |   `-- eggs-hw.tex
        `-- spam-hw.tex
```